# Runtime Complexity

Tags: big-o

I was doing this example (https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/computer-science/big-o-notation-and-binary-trees/big-o-practice) and the answer they gave was O(N^2). The reason being - quote, "there is a for loop inside a while loop." This is true but isn't the time comp of assigning `array[index1] = array[index2];` and `array[index2] = temporaryValue;` n. Wouldn't that take big-O to n^3.

```
function sortByValue(array){
  function swap(array, index1, index2){
    let temporaryValue = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temporaryValue;
  }
  let count = 1;
  while (count < array.length) {
    let swapCount = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<array.length-count; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        swap(array, i, i+1);
        swapCount++;
      }
    }
   count++;
 }
   return array;
}
```

Comment: That might be true if array would have been a linked list. The name array suggests otherwise.

Comment: if linked list, then one likely should not iterate by index.... When figuring complexity, it is important to understand what the n goes to.  Here n is the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the time complexity of

```
array[index1] = array[index2];
array[index2] = temporaryValue;
```

is O(1). Accessing or assigning to an array element is constant time (O(1)), and each of these lines is just assigning a single value to another variable. It follows that the entire `swap` function is O(1). Then, since there is one loop nested inside one other loop that each can take up to `array.length` iterations, the `sortByValue` function is O(n^2).

Comment: Okay Thanks. so if I hadn't been mistaken about the time complexity of the two assignments. Would my assumption that if the swap function had been O(n) then total time complexity would have been O(n^3).

Comment: If swap had something in it that made it O(n), then the total time complexity would be O(n^3), yes.